# azure ad b2c with spa and webapi

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am confused about how Azure B2C works when SPA is talking to backend APIs. We have a VUE app that retrieves data from ASPNet core Web APIs. I connected the VUE with APP on Azure B2C and I can login and retrieve access token, but.

How does authentication/authorization between SPA and APIs work?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure B2C uses OATH 2 / OpenID Connect as the main way to secure single page apps and API's.  OATH 2 uses [Json Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/) (stateless cryptographically signed tokens) to provide authentication between multiple services (OpenID Connect is an extension of OATH 2).

The Client application (the SPA in this case) would ask Azure AD B2C for JWT tokens.  If the user is logged in to B2C the security token service would then issue tokens for the SPA to use.

When the SPA calls the API, the ID token from the security token service (in the OpenID Connect flow) would be sent to the API in the `Authorization` header (`Authorization: Bearer $token$`).  The API could then validate the token based on the signature block of the JWT to validate that the token was issued by the security token service and has not been modified.  Because of the trust relationship between the STS and the API (the API trusts the STS), the API then authenticates and authorizes the various api calls based on the JWT that is presented.

Since you have the SPA working and getting tokens, all you need to do next is set up the Web API to accept the JWT from B2C.  Using [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer) the following code should be close to getting you up and running

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  { 
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
  })
  .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
  {
    jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
    jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
    jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
      OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
    };
  });
```

(above code from [azure samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi/tree/master), no longer maintained.

While Ideally both the SPA and API would be registered as separate clients with the STS, you could use the same client ID so you would not need to keep two sets of tokens around, one for the SPA client and one for the API.  In the current project I am working on, multiple SPA's are registered as clients then the API has an `AddJwtBearer` which accepts multiple audiences

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidAudiences = new List<string> 
        {
            Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId1"];,
            Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId2"]; 
        }
    };
}
```

This gives enough security to me for my app and the API does not need to be registered as a client with the IDP.

Comment: What do you mean using same client ID? When I register SPA and API in App Registration, it would generate 2 different client IDs.
#2 how are you managing roles/permissions? using Manifest?

Comment: @Ali I register all the SPA as separate clients with their own client id.  Since the JWT tokens from B2C have the valid audience set to the client id, having the API accept tokens with a valid audience of X means you dont need to register the API as a client, thus having its own client it and audience.  It validates the tokens are for the client expected.

Comment: @Ali For permissions I am using Security Groups to grant yes no access to the various applications.  The main legacy application has its own role and permission structure.  Eventually I will lift the role assignment to B2C but in the initial rollout permissions and groups are handled by each individual application.  Its not the greatest but does enable me to offload the authentication and get a quicker time to market

Answer (score -1):

I Hope you are aware of the web app/SPA registration process like

1. Select App registrations, select the Owned applications tab, and
   then select the webapp1 application.
2. Under Web, select the Add URI link, enter http://localhost:6420.
3. Under Implicit Grant, select the checkboxes for Access Tokens and ID
   Tokens and then select Save.
4. Record the Application (client) ID for use in a later step when you
   update the code in the single-page web application.

In the same manner we will create a web API

1. Select App registrations, and then select New registration.
2. Enter a Name for the application. For example, `webapi1`.
3. Under Redirect URI, select Web, and then enter an endpoint where
   Azure AD B2C should return any tokens that your application
   requests. In this tutorial, the sample runs locally and listens at
   http://localhost:5000.
4. Record the Application (client) ID for use in a later step.

Then we need to configure scopes. These Scopes provide a way to govern access to protected resources. Scopes are used by the web API to implement scope-based access control. Please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app-webapi?tabs=app-reg-ga#grant-permissions) on how to provide scope for web API.

And Need to Grant permission to the web API in the Web APP which we created at first. This permission helps the generated access token at Web APP to be validated/Autorized at the web API. Please go through the steps as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app-webapi?tabs=app-reg-ga#grant-permissions)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response, I have done the first part, for second part, I will set it up. 
But how would the SPA send tokens to WebAPIs that I have running under same port?

Comment: Once you are logged in using the Azure AD B2C a token is generated. The received token contains the  `iss` and `aud` claim information. You can see this information by [decoding the token](http://jwt.ms/). When you Grant the permission to the web API in the web app(expose API permission) in the web API you be providing the `Authority` and the `Audience` details which will validate the incoming request. Please refer this [document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi/tree/master#token-validation) for more details