# Spring Boot: How to verify Azure B2C JWT token

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, token, azure-ad-b2c

I`m using Azure B2C to log in users in my SPA and I need to verify each request in the REST API.
I think that one way to do this is by creating a JWT filter in the API.
My doubt is how to verify the user token.

Can anybody help with an example or indicate a Java library to validate the JWT?

Comment: If the API's are protect then no need of applying JWT filter at API. The Token is validate with `valid issuer` and `valid audience`.

Answer (score -1):

All Azure AD B2C tokens are signed JWTs. The sample code will find the metadata endpoint of your policy+tenant combination, and use the public key to ensure that the token signature is valid/unmodified and has been signed by the private keyholder (AAD B2C).

Please refer the [Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) The [API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) is protected using the `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` to verify the signature of the token. To know more on how Authentication and Authorization will work please refer this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052516/azure-ad-b2c-with-spa-and-webapi)